# How do I beat Pauline?

Tags: super-smash-bros-ultimate

This match seems to be a tough one.  When you spawn, a few seconds later, a Mario with a Hammer spawns immediately above you and goes to where you are.  About 15? seconds later, a permanent giant DK spawns. The goal of the match is to defeat Peach.

The problem I have seen so far amongst my futile attempts is that the Peach will constantly run away from you.  The stage is definitely not fun at all, with tons and tons of platforms.  The DK seems to suffer no hitstun because he is giant, and as a result I get smashed around constantly by him, and the Mario is just the cherry on top.   Add all that, and you still have a time limit of only 2 minutes to get the job done or you automatically fail.

I've read a few guides online to deal with this but they just don't seem to work.  One of the tips was to use the Cupid soul assist to laser the Peach off with the Staff, but from my experience, I can only get 1-2 hits on the Peach (which while it does do 30-42%, it does a very minimal amount of knockback) before the Mario comes in with the hammer forcing me to either block and endure it, or retreat to the side or the top, where the side defeats the purpose of the staff, and the top gives me no line of sight to the Peach.     Another tip was to counter the Mario with Marth, then stealing the hammer, but for whatever reason I can't consistently steal the hammer; sometimes it'll drop, sometimes it'll just knock away the Mario before he continues hammering away.  And when the hammer does drop, it only last so long, and usually doesn't last long enough to knock the Mario or DK out of the stage.

So looking for some advice on beating Pauline. Kinda peeving me that her stage is the only one sitting there on the entire map, and for completion sake I'd love to just get it over with. I'm currently sitting on normal difficulty but I'd be open for tips for hard mode as well, since I plan on trying hard after I finish World of Light on Normal.

Comment: Who were your other two supports? If you go in with spirit advantage and Pocket Football + Pigma, two shots from the staff should be enough to KO (example [here](https://youtu.be/31eDDtOisMg))

Comment: I was running a 3 slot spirit with 2 ranged item damage up and lightweight

Comment: @scohe001 that video would be a good start for an answer, especially since that strat kills Pauline in 5 seconds

Comment: @Malco I thought the same, but it sounds like OP already tried that strategy or some variation of it, so I don't think it would benefit them.

Comment: I strongly suggest practicing with the staff method that you mentioned. It takes three shots from the side of the stage that you start on to knock Peach out. If you can land two already, it just takes a little bit of practice to get the third in. That's how I did it.

Comment: You were running a 3 slot spirit, but did it have a type advantage? And what level was it? Pauline is fairly high leveled (13,700!), so it's possible the staff strategy isn't working if your spirit level isn't comparable. The video shows the player with his level just over 12k, but I was able to beat the level with the same strategy at around 10k with type advantage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you are still having the problem, what I did was use Solid Snake, and rocket Mario until he drops the hammer. 
Then do the same to Donkey Kong, if you can bait him to pick up the hammer it's easier. You got to be very careful to not fall off the stage.

Now all you have to deal with is Peach, and I can't say whether I can offer a consistent strategy for her. 
I got a few rocket hits on her barely, she usually shields or dodges, I also tried to melee her, the only thing I relied on to finish her was the double final smash perk which is very easy to target her with. The only problem using the double final smash is the time limit, so best of luck, this is what worked for me though. As for spirits, I'm not in memory on what I used against her, try to use something to complement Snake. I think Revolver Ocelot upgraded is what I used as my main one.

Answer (score 1):

The following strategy worked for me: use a spirit that makes you start with a staff, plus two spirits that increase ranged item attack. The staff has infinite range and shoots in a straight line, so you can shoot Peach from all the way across the stage (where she won't be running away). With a strong Legendary level 99 primary spirit in the right color, you can kill her in about three shots.

Comment: The OP mentioned this strategy in their question, and claimed they were having trouble with it.

Comment: Oh, I missed that. It's not clear if they followed exactly the strategy I listed, and if any changes might have affected the success of the attempt. I've made it more specific to try to address that.

Comment: This strategy worked for me. I used Kirby, shot once before Mario spawns, then went down and floated between the lowest platforms and Mario fell between with his hammer. Then another shot or two finished the job.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. Play as Solid Snake,

Step 2. Maxed out revolver ocelot spirit

Step 3. jump improvement spirit, and shooting attack up

Step 4. Spam The rocket launcher until victory. It will even overpower peach if she shields

Answer (score -1):

I used Kirby, lvl 99 wolf link and midna + staff equipped and two shooting ^ spirits, ignored Mario and took out peach with three shots before Mario Or DK got to me.

Answer (score -3):

The following will take some tries:
 1. Use Marth.
 2. Go to the top left.
 3. Counter the hammer.
 4. Get to the right of Mario.
 5. Counter until he drops the hammer.
 6. Throw him to the left edge.
 7. Throw DK to the left edge.
 8. Chase Peach while attacking her.
 9. When she's at high damage, knock her off!

Comment: But how does that work in this specific fight? When you start, both you and Peach are on opposite sides of the stage, and a Mario with a hammer automatically spawns in directly above you.

Comment: Changed the answer to include stage-specific strats and accommodate new recollections.

Comment: So you took the guide that was put up on that website and retranslated here. However, there's a few issues with that method.  One, it's not perfectly consistent to get Mario to drop the hammer, like I noted in my question.  Two, it's easy to say that you can "throw them off the left edge" but this doesn't translate very well to the real fight when  you can get easily knocked out of the grab by the other fighter.

Comment: You have infinite retries in WoL.

Comment: Doesn't mean I have infinite patience to retry infinitely

Comment: It took me 10 minutes, I believe.

Answer (score -3):

Use Mr. Game and Watch's Final Smash with Hero Chao with Ashley it increase the Final Smash meter. Just charge the FS meter away from Peach. You might die due to Mr. G&M's light weight but when you use his FS just charge into Peach and drag her off the stage. This took me 2 tries but I did it.